# PERROR torsocks: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, proxy, torsocks

Sometimes,if not often,the IP address assigned to me by TOR does not work. Is there a way to choose the exit IP numbers where my traffic should exit the Tor network ? I've found a script that tells to be able to change the TOR IP number exit node in a specific time frame. It's called "auto-change-tor-ip" ; unfortunately it does not work. The IP number does not change at all. What I did has been to create a list of IP numbers generated using these websites :

https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes

https://github.com/SecOps-Institute/Tor-IP-Addresses

I put them inside a text file called "listip.txt" that I have saved inside the directory "/home/user/Downloads/auto-change-tor-ip/

After that I tried to run the script called "auto-change-tor-ip" that you can find here :

https://github.com/noobpk/auto-change-tor-ip/

but in my case it didn't work. As I said,the IP never changes (I'm running ubuntu 23.10).

This is what happens,instead :

```
[*] Detect Platform
[INFO] - [*] Linux - KALI LINUX - UBUNTU
[INFO] - [+] Check Requirement
/usr/sbin/tor
/usr/bin/torsocks
/usr/sbin/privoxy
[INFO] - [*] Tor has been installed
[INFO] - [*] TorSocks has been installed
[INFO] - [*] Privoxy has been installed
[INFO] - [*] File listip.txt has been created
[INFO] - [*] Current IP Addresss
71.35.27.189
[INFO] - [*] Start service Tor
[INFO] - [*] Start service Privoxy
[INFO] - [*] Add to your browsers HTTP Proxy 127.0.0.1:8118
[INFO] - [*] Access Privoxy Manager http://p.p/
[INFO] - [*] Set time stamp
[?] Time to auto change ip by second (default 600s):30
[?] Number of loop (default 144):
[INFO] - [*] Change New IP

**PERROR torsocks[44152]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)**

[INFO] - [*] Successfully - Your IP has been Changed
[INFO] - [*] New IP Addresss:
71.35.27.189
    
    ^CKeyboardInterrupt
```

These are the parameters that I'm using on the configuration files :

```
/etc/tor/torrc :

RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 62464
Nickname superman
BridgeRelay 1

/etc/tor/torsocks.conf

TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9150
OnionAddrRange 127.42.42.0/24

on my router I opened ports : 62464 ; 9150 ; 9050 ; 9100 ; 8118 ;
```

Someone can help me to fix it ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script's source - it's a timeout happening or unhandled call by the exit node. This case is not covered by the script you've mentioned. the right thing to do is to use tor TransPort transparent proxy feature and make a full routing through it. Also it's a great idea to prevent this kind of problems is to add/write a connection monitoring script that will fire up right after `signal NEWNYM` and before marking IP as changed

Comment: ohhh thanks. But I'm not so experienced that I can fix the script as you have suggested. The only thing I can do is to find a more complete script of the same kind. Can you give me some suggestion ? thanks.

Comment: just make a "tor router box" - I do recommend using raspberry pi or similar for a physical one or a virtual machine. What is your case? If you'll describe it more details maybe I'll be able to help you better. For a virtual machines try QubesOS ( FORGET buggy Whonix! )

Comment: my ultimate goal is to install a working TOR ip changer on FreeBSD,using the Linuxulator.

Comment: I love FreeBSD too, used to teach a course of that of my own design :) So - you don't need linux emulation, basically - Tor used to support BPF facility that is blazing fast and built-in into FreeBSD kernel. The script you want has to be based on the github one you posted with a checker fired up as I said, install it in a separate venv and put into DJB's daemontools called from /etc/ttys - a bulletproof setup!